# Unable to save changes to UAC?

Tags: windows-8, uac

I am having issues with the user account control settings on my laptop. I change them and rebooted and they are fine until I reboot again and they re-set back to the highest level. There are a number of apps that won’t work with these settings:

Camera, Video, Skype, Picture editor, voicemail playback.

Key Points:

- I am running Windows 8
- Metro apps will not run
- I am able to enable UAC but after reboot, UAC is disabled again but there is no GPO in        place which forces this.

Has anyone came across and have solved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a program that runs as part of startup on Windows 8 which will automatically change UAC to whatever level is configured.

To access the settings follow the steps below:

- Press Win+R on your keyboard and then enter "msconfig" (without the quotes) and hit enter
- Click the "Tools" tab at the top
- Select "Change UAC Settings" and then click "Launch" toward the bottom right
- Set User Account Control to whatever level you'd like to have the system reset to after each reboot (in your case, any level above the lowest (which will disable UAC) will do the trick)
- Reboot your computer to test that UAC is configured at the level you desire

[This site](http://www.guidingtech.com/2567/disable-user-account-control-uac-windows-vista-7/) also has a good step-by-step explanation (written for Windows Vista but should still work for Windows 8)

Good luck!